# How to remove googles cache/cookies from oauth for a login terminal used by multiple people

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, webkit, google-signin

I'm creating an application to be used in a public area. People will go up to a mounted iPad to signin, then proceed to use the app and logout. The default functionality keeps their google login information. I don't want this, I want to delete all of the google authentication data on logout so we don't have a list of accounts.

I've found some resources here on SO, none are using react-native though so maybe thats my issue? This is running through the package `react-native-google-sign-in` which is a wrapper for `GIDSignIn`, and I can't find where this package is opening the webview controller, so I thought the best solution would be to delete the cache/cookies.

I've created a bridge between react-native and ios, so I'm able to write Swift. I've tried a few methods but none seem to give back any login information for me to delete

```
  let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
  dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { (records) in
    print("MARK: RECORDS \(records)")
    for record in records {
      if record.displayName.contains("google") {
        dataStore.removeData(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(), for: [record], completionHandler: {
          print("Deleted: " + record.displayName);
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Also I've tried this:

```
  if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
      for cookie in cookies {
          print("MARK: COOOKIE \(cookie)")
          HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
      }
  }
```

but here I just get an empty array.

this one seemed promising.. finding the folder this stuff lives in and removing it?, but I'm not 100% sure how it works/where to look for the cached data

```
  var libraryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.libraryDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first!
  libraryPath += "/Cookies"

  do {
    let result = try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: libraryPath)
    print("MARK: SUCCESSSSS \(result)")
  } catch {
    print("MARK: error")
  }
```

no luck. got an empty array. I also got an empty array from this response

```
  HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)
  print("MARK: [WebCacheCleaner] All cookies deleted")

  WKWebsiteDataStore.default().fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
    records.forEach { record in
      WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: record.dataTypes, for: [record], completionHandler: {})
      print("MARK: [WebCacheCleaner] Record \(record) deleted")
    }
  }
```

I've added this to every attempt as well:

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

I don't even know if these past logins are stored as 'cookies', all I know is when I go into Settings > Safari > delete website data... the accounts are removed. Some of these attempts were from me translating obj-c to swift, if anything stands out as wrong that'd be super helpful.

Comment: Same issue here. Have you found a solution? 
Will post if i get any progress.

Comment: I ran out of budget and had to remove gmail completely since I couldn't find the solution. Would love to know if you find anything.

Comment: @NicolasVignolo ,  was there any lawsuit involved in this? I'm having the same issue.